# navigation bar and tableview cell height for ipad

Tags: ios, ipad

Do we need to change the height of navigation bar and tableView cell height for iPad in universal app. To increase the height of navigation bar for iPad I am using,

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad
{

}
```

Comment: Are you using the same screens for both?

Comment: yes. I am using same screens for both iphone and ipad

Comment: Then there is no need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No don't change the navigation bar height  it is  the same on both iPhone & iPad
the cell depend on your design the width will increase so you should increase the  height . or you can use another cell with another design for the iPad